# use AI to creat images from texts

Tags: training

I want to use AI to create art images from a single text available in different languages, with the generated images being different depending on the language of the given text.

example 1:

step 1: the input text is orginal : "It does not do well to dwell on dreams and forget to live."

step 2 ( whatever it means) : AI tech. generates a corresponding image X

example 2 :

step 1: the input original text is translated into French : "Il n'est pas bon de s'attarder sur les rêves et d'oublier de vivre.

step 2 : AI tech. generates a corresponding image Y, diffrent from the image X due to the fact that the text language has changed

I believe one way to achieve this is by training a single AI model that can handle multiple languages and can produce different styles based on each language.

Any ideas on the end to end process and costs ( say for a bilingual corps of 1000 words ) ?

Thanks

Comment: To what extend do models such as DallE already do this for you? If you give a prompt in a different language, i reckon they give some other kind of image?